# How to Allow Multiple Business Users to Autogenerate Paypal Express Client Id for an Angular App via an API

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, paypal

I do understand that I should be posting this question in the Paypal Developers Help section but I'm not sure what is the right keyword to ask and look for, especially when reading their Docs and API docs.

I'm using **NodeJS as Backend** and **Angular 7 as Frontend**. What I want to do is to allow "**Business Users**" to link their Paypal Account (Client ID) to their credentials.

The app I'm building is a very simple e-commerce website where Business User can only sell one type of product.

The logic is:

- Business User will create an account to my app
- They will be allowed to link their PayPal account for selling products and other transactions
- Then Normal user or customer will be able to purchase (This part is easy and already implemented via Paypal Express Checkout API)
- However, I want each payment to go directly to the Business user Paypal Account (There could be multiple business users)

I know I need to generate a client Id to make Paypal Payment work by configuring it at Paypal Developer Dashboard but I want the client ID to be auto-generated via API or REST API.

Again, I'm not sure what is the right keyword to search for when integrating this to my Angular 7 app with a Node JS Backend.

So, I'll appreciate anyone that can point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.